# How to access /var/lib/mysql folder in ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, docker

I'm creating a docker container with volume but I can't access the container directory, does anyone know how to solve this?

The command used is this:

```
docker run --name Mysql -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:latest
```

Comment: Will any other MySQL installation use the same directory? Or will just this one Docker container use it?

Comment: only this docker container will use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with directory permissions. The `/var/lib/mysql/` directory is owned by `mysql`. If *only* a single Docker container will use this directory, you can change its ownership to the same account that operates Docker.

For example:

```
sudo chown -R rafael:rafael /var/lib/mysql
```

Doing this will allow the Docker container to access all of the files that currently exist in that given directory, which may be useful if you are trying to ensure MySQL is always a specific version while keeping the core OS up to date with security patches.

Comment: Setting like this with my directory does not store the data? -v ~/volume/mysql/data:/data/db thank you.

Comment: That will use a directory different from `/var/lib/mysql`, but will work just as fine if you are happy with that location. So long as the permissions are correct, the data can be stored in any directory on the host.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

docker run --name Mysql -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -v ~/volume/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:latest